# Select statement with sum and limit

Tags: php, mysql

What's wrong with this query and how can i output the result?

```
`SELECT sum(BM) from (SELECT rpdc.BM from rpdc LIMIT $start, $limit) as totalbm`
```

Comment: My problem is when i try to output the result. Like echo "TOTAL BM".$row['totalbm']; it is undefined index totalbm

Answer (score 1):

You need to give an alias for the sum something as

```
SELECT 
sum(BM) as total_sum 
from (SELECT rpdc.BM from rpdc LIMIT $start, $limit) as totalbm
```

Then in php you can use as

```
$row['total_sum'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey you need to add as 'some_name' like SELECT name **as firstname**

Replcae with this **sum(BM) as total** 
So, result array will treat total_sum as key of array.
You can use it as **$result['total']**